# 16.10 broke my MythTV

Tags: mysql, tv, mythtv

I just upgraded from 16.04.1 to 16.10, and now MythTV 0.28 is broken. It worked fine in 16.04.1.

Specifically it's the **mythtv-frontend** that's broken. It won't start, and this throws this error:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: /usr/bin/mythfrontend.real terminated
```

The **mythtv-backend** seems to be running fine... which probably means that the MySQL database is working fine too.

There's not much additional information that I can provide. Can anybody help?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash on mythfrontend startup has been fixed with release 0.28.0+fixes.20161106.1434df8-0ubuntu0mythbuntu2.

Mythfrontend now starts and runs, but crashes on exit with seg fault.